# re-format excel 2010 worksheet based on existing formating

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I get an excel as output from another application.   Unfortunately, it's not in the format I want.   The columns are fixed, but the rows, row content and row formatting vary based on what's in the report.

Question is, what's the best way to be able to "read" existing formating of an excel spreadsheet, do some reformatting of text and excel "underlining, etc." and then build the excel I want?

I had assumed it was VBA, but after looking into that for a while, I'm not convinced that's the answer.

Any opinions?

Comment: Look at [conditional formatting](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=excel+conditional+formatting), which keys off your data to apply certain formatting styles to not only a specific part of your data (such as one cell), but can also apply a style to a whole area (row, column, range) based on a combination of factors. You can also use VBA to clear existing formatting and apply your own (even to apply conditional formatting), but this all depends on what makes sense to you and your data.